# Cosmos DB Newtonsoft Deserialization Issue

Tags: c#, json.net, azure-cosmosdb

I am having a strange issue with CosmosDb unable to deserialise my class.

The error I am getting is

> Could not create an instance of type TestApp.Entities.IVisitItem. Type is an
>   interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated

I have the following code in my startup class

```
 JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
        };
```

And when I look in the Data Explorer and look at my document, I can see that the type information is saved correctly

```
  "VisitItems": [
            {
                "$type": "TestApp.Entities.NoteVisitItem, TestApp.Entities",
                "Note": "fsfsdfdsfsdf",
                "VisitId": "22931c75-efb4-59ea-5b1b-7533bd8bb570",
                "VisitItemType": "Note",
                "Created": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
                "CreatedById": null,
                "CreatedByName": null,
                "Id": "1e6233cf-e970-4b9f-b60b-a8fb62c94c81"
            }
        ]
```

If anyone can shed any light on what else I need to be doing to get this to deserialise correctly it would be appreciated.

BTW this is a .net core 2.1 project using Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB/2.0.0-preview2.

I am using NewtonsoftJson 11.0.2 on all projects and this looks to be the same version the DocumentDB libraries are using.

Update -- here is my data access code

```
  public class CosmosDocumentDbClient : IDbClient
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string,Uri> _collectionLinks = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Uri>();
    private readonly IList<IDisposable> _disposables = new List<IDisposable>();
    private DocumentClient _client;
    private string _databaseId;

    public CosmosDocumentDbClient(IConfigurationRegister configurationRegister)
    {
        var subscription = configurationRegister.Configuration<CosmosDbConfiguration>().Subscribe(c =>
        {
            this._databaseId = c.DatabaseId;
            this._client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(c.EndpointUri), c.Key);

            this.InitialiseDb(this._client, c.DatabaseId, "Case", "Owner").Wait();
        });

        _disposables.Add(subscription);
    }

    public async Task Initialise()
    {
    }

    public IQueryable<TEntity> GetCollection<TEntity>()
    {
        return this._client.CreateDocumentQuery<TEntity>(GetCollectionLink(typeof(TEntity).Name));
    }

    public async Task<List<TEntity>> ToListAsync<TEntity>(Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IQueryable<TEntity>> items)
    {
        return  await items.Invoke(
            this._client.CreateDocumentQuery<TEntity>(GetCollectionLink(typeof(TEntity).Name)))
            .ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<TEntity> FirstOrDefaultAsync<TEntity>(IQueryable<TEntity> query)
    {
        return (await query.Take(1).ToListAsync()).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public async Task<TEntity> Get<TEntity>(string id)
    {           
       var docUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(_databaseId, typeof(TEntity).Name,id);
       return await _client.ReadDocumentAsync<TEntity>(docUri);
    }

    public async Task Insert<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : IEntity
    {
        await _client.UpsertDocumentAsync(GetCollectionLink(typeof(TEntity).Name), entity);
    }

    public  async Task Update<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : IEntity
    {
        try
        {
            var docUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(_databaseId, typeof(TEntity).Name,entity.Id);
            await _client.ReplaceDocumentAsync(docUri, entity);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }

    }

    private async Task InitialiseDb(DocumentClient client, string databaseId, params string[] collectionIds)
    {
        await client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(new Database() {Id = databaseId});

        foreach (var collectionId in collectionIds)
        {
            await client.CreateDocumentCollectionIfNotExistsAsync(
                UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri(databaseId), new DocumentCollection {Id = collectionId});
        }
    }

    private Uri GetCollectionLink(string collectionName)
    {
        if (!_collectionLinks.ContainsKey(collectionName))
        {
            _collectionLinks.TryAdd(collectionName,
                UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(_databaseId, collectionName));
        }
        return _collectionLinks[collectionName];
    }
```

Comment: I’m not doing the deserialisation, the CosmosDb client library is doing it. I googled this and from what I found adding the TypeNameHandling = auto should be enough and works for others I guess. It uses Newtonsoft Json under the hood. Maybe there is somewhere else I need to specify the Serialiser Settings. But the changes I made caused it to record the type information so why it’s not respecting it on the deserialise is odd.

Comment: Ok I was indeed wrong, I got it working with the same JsonConvert.Default settings and with the following [data access code](https://i.imgur.com/l0gCN29.png). My entities look like [this](https://i.imgur.com/vAAlAIG.png). Can you please share your data access code?

Comment: Will do as soon as I get home in about 20 mins

Comment: Ok, added data access code, its basically the ToListAsync Method i'm using to create the document query. I see you are using Cosmonaut client whereas i'm using Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB/2.0.0-preview2. Can't find anything on the DocumentClient for JsonSerialiser Settings

Comment: Ok think I have it!   this._client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(c.EndpointUri), c.Key, serializerSettings: new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
                } );

Comment: Yep that fixes it! I think it's crazy that it uses the default static settings for serialisation and then uses a different settings instance when de-serialising! You did suggest that in your previous comments so if you want to answer again i'll accept, thanks for your time. I guess Cosmonaut is solving that issue for you.

Comment: Awesome! Yeah I added the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, as we concluded through comments.

The `DocumentClient` of CosmosDB has it's own `JsonSerialiser` settings object which is where you need to configure the `TypeNameHandling` setting.

Setting it only on the `JsonConvert.DefaultSettings` level will make it work on serialisation but it fails during deserialisation.

Adding it at the `DocumentClient` level will fix the issue.